# Во всех таблицах и вьюшках текущей схемы найти первые по алфавиту столбцы среди столбцов

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select user_tables.table_name, user_tab_columns.column_name
from user_tables
left join user_tab_columns on user_tables.table_name=user_tab_columns.column_name
where user_tab_columns.column_name = (select min(user_tab_columns.column_name) from user_tab_columns)
```

Вот что пока получилось, но данный запрос выводит только минимальную лексикографически столбец среди всех столбцов, а мне необходимо найти относительно каждой вьюшки или таблицы такой столбец

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() в CTE и выбор `rn=1` в основном запросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не стоит джойнить не нужные для ответа на вопрос таблицы:

```
select table_name, min(column_name) 
from user_tab_cols
group by table_name
```